# Solvation of uranyl formate/acetate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, structural-formula

Uranyl formate has a structure something like:

$\ce{UO2-(OCHO)2}$

So the structural formulae I've seen have two double-bonded oxygens directly attached to the U and each formate group is attached by single bonds to the oxygens. Like [this.](http://images.chemnet.com/suppliers/chembase/cas3/cas16984-59-1.gif)
The empirical formula for the dry powder is written as a monohydrate.

Can someone explain how this thing gets solvated in water and what the solvated ions are, exactly? I just realized I was assuming it dissociates into a 'uranyl' ion (whatever that looks like) and two formate ions$\ldots$but then I'm confused about where the formate's oxygen goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a uranyl ion, one of the most common forms of dissolved uranium:

[image: Uranyl]

Because the two U=O bonds can form a single delocalised region, there's a strong tendency towards linearity (*c.f.* carbon dioxide). It tends to dissolve in water by gaining equatorial water ligands (4 or 5), some of which it may then hydrolyse, depending on the pH:

[image: Hydrated uranyl and hydrolysed form]

The axial oxygen atoms are also valid targets for hydrogen bonding, typically gaining one hydrogen bond each.

[image: Axial oxygen hydrogen bond]

The difficulty in dissolving uranyl formate in particular suggests that the formate ion is quite well-bound, and it seems that in this case you get a combination of water and formate ligands in the complex around the uranyl. I was expecting the formate to be a bi-dentate ligand, but according to the [results of a combined computational and experimental study](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C3DT51711J) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2yvF.png), it's uni-dentate (which incidentally allows it to form polymeric chains in solution).

Here's a picture from that study showing a computationally obtained structure of a mixed water/formate-ligated uranyl structure.

[image: Combination water and formate uranyl ion]

1. **2013**, Dalton Trans., Christian Lucks, André Rossberg, Satoru Tsushima, Harald Foerstendorf, Karim Fahmya, Gert Bernharda, [DOI:10.1039/C3DT51711J](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C3DT51711J)